# display message on wrong password entry

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function

I have a submit button which only works when "victory" is typed into the form. Now I am trying to work on an error message to display "wrong keyword entry" if the text entered into the form field isn't "victory". here is the code

```
<form name="input" action="index.html" method="post" onsubmit="return check();">
<input type="text" maxlength="7" autocomplete="off" name="" id="victory">

<br><input type="submit" class="bigbutton"  value="NEXT">

</form>    
<script>

function check(){
if(document.getElementById("victory").value == "victory")
    return true;
else 
   return false;
```

}

Comment: When you say "work on", what exactly do you want it to do?

Comment: I don't want a pop out notification. Something to appear on the page itself @CraigBrett

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were you I'd add an HTML element to stuff an error into. Then you can style it with CSS however you'd like.

```
<div id="error"></div>
```

Then your function would look something like this:

```
function check(){
    if(document.getElementById("victory").value == "victory")
        return true;
    else 
        document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Wrong keyword entry."
        return false;
}
```

Comment: this addresses the issue of the error, it fails at making sure the value entered only works for "victory" @ElliotSchmelliot

Comment: I dont follow. I thought you wanted to submit your form when "victory" was typed.

Comment: I finally got it to work but some adjustments were made on your code. Thanks. i will put up the working code in my post @ElliotSchmelliot

Comment: Dont change your original post, thats not where answers are supposed to go. Usually you mark one of these answers as "correct" so other people can reference it as well as your original question.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add the alert in the `else` condition…

```
function check(){
   if(document.getElementById("victory").value == "victory") {
        return true;
   }
   else {    
        alert("wrong keyword entry");
        return false;
   }
 }
```